# Observer is not available - Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed elixir as per instructions given in the [offical website](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html) ran the following lines in console and everything works fine

```
Add Erlang Solutions repo: wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
Run: sudo apt-get update
Run: sudo apt-get install elixir
```

But when i run *:observer.start* in the *iex shell*,i get the following error

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: :observer.start/0 (module :observer is not available)
>       :observer.start()

I ran a few commands after looking up the net, to solve the issue

```
apt list | grep -i erlang
```

It gave back many lines of which this could be relevance

> erlang-observer/unknown 1:18.0 amd64

Any help on how to make it work?

**Update**

It seems that other modules like :dbg and :mnesia is working. Though I cant confirm if all the modules are working. Also wonder why some are working and some arent?

Comment: I am Mac so for me `:observer.start` properly starts the Erlang observer gui, as expected. The error you sent `module :observer is not available` - it seems the erlang module is missing.

If your application or interactive shell makes a call to an unknown erlang module, then I think you should have some  `erl_crash.dump` file containing more details to it. Will this tool http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html and details help you to zero down the issue?

Comment: and here is a source to Erlang/OTP observer application if you want to manually build it - ftp://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/factory/x86_64/erlang-observer-src-18.0.2-2.1.x86_64.html

Comment: @TechFuel, there is no crash dump when calling from iex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you be sure Erlang was also installed from Erlang Solutions? Distributions are known to break Erlang into multiple packages (Erlang Solutions does not), so if observer is not available, you very likely need to install erlang-observer indeed.

Comment: except for the three lines of code i wrote in the question description, i have not done anything else in installation. I supposed that everything was automatically(and appropriately) installed, since elixir was working properly. Can you tell me how to install erlang-observer individually?Or should i remove then reinstall erlang from erlang-solutions

Comment: Observer is not a Elixir dependency so, if Ubuntu broke erlang into multiple packages, I imagine you will need to run  `apt-get install erlang-observer` to get it. Or just uninstall erlang and get the one from erlang solutions, as you said.

Comment: thanks that did it, I'l post the complete answer for others to see better

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem running `iex -S mix`
It was fixed by adding `:wx`, `:observer` and `:runtimetools` to `extra_applications`.

```
  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger, :eex, :wx, :observer, :runtime_tools]
    ]
  end
```

Comment: Maybe you read it here https://elixirforum.com/t/cannot-start-observer-undefinedfunctionerror-function-observer-start-0-is-undefined/56642/2?u=adamu

Comment: This is relevant when observer is working from iex, but not from iex -S mix. Had the exact same problem and it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JoseValim, simply re-running the commands(without deleting anything) helped me. I think the first time I must have had some internet connectivity issue.

```
Add Erlang Solutions repo: wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
Run: sudo apt-get update
Run: sudo apt-get install elixir
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that the observer requires a GUI.

**When this may not be clear**: if you are running *iex* on WSL and using remote-connection from VS Code or through any terminal connected to WSL.

There aren't any issues with developing on this setup, but if you need an observer it isn't going to be available through the terminal connected to WSL because of the lack of GUI. There are some options available to install a GUI on WSL for remote connection from the Windows machine, but I suspect this would result in the same outcome if using Windows tooling with WSL.